# cran.r-project.org is down and has been down for over 20 hours - any ideas what is going on? 11/15/23

Tags: r, cran

cran.r-project.org is down and it is really messing up my day. Not only has it been down today, but it has been down for over 20 hours according to [this website](https://www.isitdownrightnow.com/cran.r-project.org.html) and the screenshots below. Does anyone know what is going on or when we can expect it back up?

[image: cran.r-project.org is down]

[image: is it down can screenshot]

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2023-November/478561.html

Comment: Yikes, that’s a long outage! If there’s something specific you’re trying to do (e.g. install packages, download binaries etc), let us know because there’s probably another way to achieve it

Comment: It wasn't 20 hours.  My CRANberriesFeed looks for updates hourly, and you can look the time stamps in the RSS feed or Mastodon toots.  I.e., right now, hours after that statement, I see most recent pulses as 14, 15, and 16 hours ago.  Let's see what the Vienna-time morning brings.  I don't think the world is ending quite yet.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a programming issue but an announced temporary resource availability issue. By the time 17 November rolls around this question is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was announced *on the CRAN site* yesterday (or the day before yesterday) and I saw at least two social media mentions:

[image]

You can still access the mirrors. One example it the CDN you can reach at https://cloud.r-project.org.  And I would expect the main site to keep its word and to be back 'soon', likely by Nov 16 as scheduled.

Comment: `R CMD check` doesn't seem to want to use any mirrors. Package dependencies and test dependencies take 3 minutes each to time out (continuing at this time). Still, 48 hours of no new package releases... the bliss and the quiet! Almost as peaceful as fresh snow on a late December morning.

Comment: IIRC it uses `options(repos)` so if you set that you should be fine. In any event you can also check _without the remote lookup_ as `R CMD check` of course has a ''no internet mode'. See about setting environment variable `_R_CHECK_CRAN_INCOMING_` and `_R_CHECK_CRAN_INCOMING_REMOTE_` to a value of `FALSE` for example via file `~/.R/check.Renviron`.  CRAN is also coming back it seems (at least sporadically) as my CRANberriesFeed already reported three updated packages.